# using <mcarries> in MathML

Tags: mathjax, mathml

I am new to coding and trying to write elementary math functions using MathML on MathJax 2.6.1. We recently acquired the  function to be able to "carry" numbers in long addition, subtraction, etc. 
Can someone show me how to implement this extension?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear if you are asking how to write MathML that includes `<mcarries>`, or if you are asking how to get MathJax to process `<mcarries>` elements.  For the former, see the [MathML specification examples](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML3/chapter3.html#presm.elemmath.examples).  For the latter, you need to load the [`mml3` extension](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/mathml.html#experimental-mml3-extension), which says to include

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  MathML: {
    extensions: ["mml3.js"]
  }
});
</script>
```

somewhere *before* the script that loads `MathJax.js` itself.